# How to avoid serializing the float array properties

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, json.net

I have used a float array property for CustomDashPattern and used it like below code,

```
float[] customDashPattern = { 5, 3, 5, 3 };

public float[] CustomDashPattern
{
   get
   {
       return customDashPattern;
   }  
   set
   {
       customDashPattern = value;
   }
}

public bool ShouldSerializeCustomDashPattern()
{
    return customDashPattern != new float[] { 5, 3, 5, 3 };
}
```

but still the property value is serialized in designer even when its default value is not changed.

The logic for should serialize returns true even when pattern is default value.

Could any one please let me know, what i have done wrong ?

Comment: It *always* returns true.  Array does not overload operator!=() so you get the simple reference comparison.  Which will never match.  Fix with             return !customDashPattern.SequenceEqual(new float[] { 5, 3, 5, 3 });

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks for your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arrays the `!=` operator compares object references. To compare arrays contents use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeCustomDashPattern()
{
    return !Enumerable.SequenceEqual(customDashPattern, new float[] { 5, 3, 5, 3 })
}
```